# Error when trying to fit data to gamma distribution

Tags: r

Here is my code:

```
data("airquality")
head(airquality)

Solar <- airquality$Solar.R

library(fitdistrplus)
fit.solar <- fitdist(Solar, distr = "gamma", method = "mle")
```

Any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: Hey, it helps to show the error. You have NA values and this is not allowed. Do, fitdist(Solar[!is.na(Solar)],..)

Answer (score 2):

The `class` is `integer`, if we convert to `numeric`, it works (after removing the missing values). According to `?fitdist`

> data - A numeric vector.

```
fitdist(as.numeric(na.omit(Solar)), distr = 'gamma', method = 'mle')
#Fitting of the distribution ' gamma ' by maximum likelihood 
#Parameters:
#        estimate  Std. Error
#shape 2.45136943 0.265264590
#rate  0.01318298 0.001573501
```

Comment: Really surprising (and not in a good way) that `fitdistrplus`, an established and widely used package, doesn't naturally handle this ...

Comment: @BenBolker  Yes, I was also surprised about the `NA` and integer to numeric strictness